# Add or remove class in change event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a problem with addClass / removeClass methods in change method event handler.

I've registered my handler like this:

```
$('.someSelector').change(MyHandler);
```

and in MyHandler I have

```
function MyHandler(){
  var input = $(this);
  input.addClass('something'); //not working
}
```

after page loading I'm getting once again this input via console, I'm executing the same code and everything works correctly. So what's the problem with change method?

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/zyqd6Lnm/) in Firefox.

Comment: How do you change the value of the selector?

Comment: It's input. Change hander is indeed executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after page loading I'm getting once again this input via console, I'm executing the same code and everything works correctly

So it means that you didn't have DOM ready when you attempted to bind event for the first time. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.someSelector').change(MyHandler);
});
```

Comment: You're right - it's something with document loading - I have a bit complicated site structure (iframe inside) and this is my bet.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {      
  $('.someSelector').change(MyHandler);      
});

function MyHandler(){

  var input = $(this);
  input.addClass('something'); 
}
```

```css
.something{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="someSelector">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```